# Поменять DIV местами если экран меньше 992px

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью Javascript поменять 'div' местами по вертикали.
 - Должен применяться если экран меньше 992px
 - Отменяться если стал больше 991px

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var block_1 = document.getElementById("block_1");
    var block_2 = document.getElementById("block_2");
    block_1.style.marginTop = block_2.offsetHeight + "px";
    block_2.style.marginTop = -(block_1.offsetHeight + block_2.offsetHeight) + "px";
}
```

```css
#block_1 {
    height:50px;
    background:red;   
}
#block_2 {
    height:35px;
    background:green;  
}
```

```html
<div id="block_1">Блок 1</div>
<div id="block_2">Блок 2</div>
```

Comment: Используй css, а не js.

Comment: Как именно ?
- Мне кажется в этом случае только javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например без js - `flex` (`oreder` - задает порядок расположения):

```css
#block_1 {
    height:50px;
    background:red;   
}
#block_2 {
    height:35px;
    background:green;  
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px){      

  #block_2 {
    order: 1;
  }
  
  #block_1 {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="block_1">Блок 1</div>
  <div id="block_2">Блок 2</div>
</div>
```

[Кроссбраузерность flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) . Кстати [bootstrap4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) и в сетке использует уже flex/

---

Вариант с `table`:

```css
#block_1>div {
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
#block_2>div {
    height:35px;
    background:green;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  #block_1 {
    display:table-footer-group;  
  }

  #block_2 {
    display:table-header-group;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="block_1">
    <div>
      Блок 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="block_2">
    <div>
      Блок 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Вариант с `jquery`:

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
  var win = $(window),
      bl1 = $('#block_1'),
      bl2 = $('#block_2'),
      h1 = bl1.height(),
      h2 = bl2.height();
      
      
  if(win.width() < 520){
    
    bl2.css({
      'transform' :'translateY(- ' + h1 + 'px)',
      '-webkit-transform' :'translateY(' + -h1 + 'px)'
    });
    bl1.css({
      'transform' :'translateY(' +  h2 + 'px)',
      '-webkit-transform' :'translateY(' +  h2 + 'px)'
    });    
  } else {
     bl2.css({
      'transform' :'translateY(0px)',
      '-webkit-transform' :'translateY(0px)'
    });
    bl1.css({
      'transform' :'translateY(0px)',
      '-webkit-transform' :'translateY(0px)'
    }); 
  }
});
```

```css
#block_1 {
    height:50px;
    background:red;   
}
#block_2 {
    height:35px;
    background:green;  
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div id="block_1">Блок 1</div>
  <div id="block_2">Блок 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: На сколько этот вариант кроссбраузерный ?
На компьютере все гладко , на телефоне ничего не меняется местами.

Comment: попробовал 2 разных телефона , android 4+ и 6+ блоки не переставляются

Comment: @Vipz, я добавила в ответ о кроссбраузерности.

Comment: @Vipz, добавила вариант с jquery, хотя считаю это неприемлемым.

Comment: @Elena Вы в варианте с jQuery изменяете css. Тогда уже лучше делать toggle для класса, а стили перенести в css.

Comment: @YozhEzhi, ну вот так сделала) Добавьте свой вариант

Comment: Блин , как здорово что есть такое место , где можно о чем то спросить и так оперативно получать ответы. Большое всем спасибо !

Answer (score 1):

**Кроссбраузерный вариант без JS:**

```css
#block_1 {
    height:50px;
    background:red;   
}
#block_2 {
    height:35px;
    background:green;  
}
.row   { 
    display: table;  
    width:100%;
}
@media (max-width: 992px){   
    #block_1 { display: table-footer-group; }
    #block_2 { display: table-header-group; }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="block_1">Блок 1</div>
  <div id="block_2">Блок 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: аж на 30сек опередила))) добавила тоже еще табличный вариант

Comment: Блин , как здорово что есть такое место , где можно о чем то спросить и так оперативно получать ответы. Большое всем спасибо !